# Как исправить ошибку call stack?

Tags: javascript, jquery

по клику на кнопки save/del

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at String.replace ()

выдает локально

на фидле просто script error

та и мой код явно не лучший..

```js
$(document).on('click', '.personal__btn--edit', function(e){
  let wrapper = $(e.target).parents('.personal__box');
  let block = wrapper.find('.personal__btn');
  let editBtn = wrapper.find('.personal__btn--edit');
  block.show();
  editBtn.hide();
  wrapper.find('.personal__input').removeAttr('disabled').focus();
})

$(document).on('click', '.personal__change', function(e){
    let wrapper = $(e.target).parents('.personal__box');
  let block = wrapper.find('.personal__btn');
  let editBtn = wrapper.find('.personal__btn--edit');
  block.show();
  editBtn.hide();
  wrapper.find('.personal__input').removeAttr('disabled').focus();
})

$(document).on('blur', '.personal__input', function(e){
  let wrapper = $(e.target).parents('.personal__box');
  let block = wrapper.find('.personal__btn');
  let editBtn = wrapper.find('.personal__btn--edit');
  block.hide();
  editBtn.show();
  wrapper.find('.personal__input').attr('disabled', true).blur();
})

$(document).on('click', '.personal__btn--save, .personal__btn--del', function(e){
  let wrapper = $(e.target).parents('.personal__box');
  wrapper.find('.personal__input').attr('disabled', true).blur();
})
```

```html
<div class="personal__user">
  <div class="personal__box">
    <div class="personal__row">
      <label class="personal__label">имя</label>
      <div class="personal__panel">
        <button type="button" class="personal__btn personal__btn--save" style="display: none;">save</button>
        <button type="button" class="personal__btn personal__btn--del" style="display: none;">del</button>
        <button type="button" class="personal__btn personal__btn--edit">edit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="personal__holder">
      <input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="p_name" class="personal__input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end personal__box-->
  <div class="personal__box">
    <div class="personal__row">
      <label class="personal__label">фамилия</label>
      <div class="personal__panel">
        <button type="button" class="personal__btn personal__btn--save" style="display: none;">save</button>
        <button type="button" class="personal__btn personal__btn--del" style="display: none;">del</button>
        <button type="button" class="personal__btn personal__btn--edit">edit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="personal__holder">
      <input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="p_surname" class="personal__input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end personal__box-->
  <div class="personal__box">
    <div class="personal__row">
      <label class="personal__label">Телефон</label>
      <div class="personal__panel">
        <button type="button" class="personal__btn personal__btn--save" style="display: none;">save</button>
        <button type="button" class="personal__btn personal__btn--del" style="display: none;">del</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="personal__holder">
      <input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="p_phone" class="personal__input">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="personal__change">поменять номер тефону</button>
  </div>
  <!--end personal__box-->
</div>
<!--end personal__wrap-->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: сделайте свой код минимальным для демонстрации проблемы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

Ошибка намекает на то, что вы получили бесконечную рекурсию. Собственно, если обратить внимание на код, то запускают эту рекурсию событие `blur` и вызов `blur()` внутри соответствующего обработчика

*зы: `e.target` в jquery это `this`*

Comment: понятно, спасибо. А код можно немного улучшить?

Comment: @nastya возможно имеет смысл скрывать/показывать элементы или их дизейблить переключая класс враппера, а-ля нажали Редактировать, класс `is-editing`  добавили, кнопки скрылись, инпут доступен для редактирования. ну а так, не смысл объявлять переменные ради одного действия (`let block ....`)

Comment: поняла, а как объявлять? вне блоков? одну переменую

Comment: @nastya нет смысла вообще объявлять `wrapper.find(...).show()` и все

Comment: всмысле? вот так сократила. Неправильно?  http://jsfiddle.net/e5nkrsdy/1/